# How to parse the json object to get "size" value from first object itself as mentioned in attached image

Tags: jq

[image]

I want to get value from first object like size in below pic.

Comment: Please provide the sample input and the corresponding expected output as text.  Also, an example of what you've tried is often helpful and generally expected.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the detailed requirements, you will probably want something like:

```
.recordset[0] | .rowsAffected[0] | .size
```

Comment: the .size is not part of recorset array. so My Json has values like: recordset, output,rowsAffected,totalsize,size ,totalpage,pagenumber.
I can directly acces it by .size but it traverse through all the objects. I mean if JOSN has 10 objects it print
10 times size values. I just need to print 1 time